# Add all items to a list that are not equal to items in another list

Tags: c#

I have a list:

```
baseList
```

And another list:

```
relatedList
```

I want to add `relatedItems` to `relatedList`, but only those items where there is not already an equal item in `baseList`.

I am thinking something like:

```
    foreach (var baseItem in baseList)
    {
         relatedList.AddRange(GetRelatedItems(baseItem)).Except(x => x in baseList);
    }
```

or

```
    foreach (var baseItem in baseList)
    {
         relatedList.AddRange(GetRelatedItems(baseItem)).Except(x => x.id not in baseList);
    }
```

But I cant figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: Can relatedList contain duplicates? How are these items related at all?

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
foreach (var baseItem in baseList)
{
    relatedList.AddRange(GetRelatedItems(baseItem)).Except(x => baseList.Where(y => x.id == y.id);
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var baseItem in baseList)
{
    relatedList.AddRange(GetRelatedItems(baseItem)).Except(x => baseList.Where(y => x.id != y.id);
}
```

Comment: If you implement `IEquatable` then this `Except()` gets a little cleaner.

Comment: I get a  syntax error at the dot just before Except. I get the message operator {dot} cannot be applied to operand of type void.

Comment: The comment from @user1283776 is proof that the answer needs an explanation. The answer has a misplaced parentheses, which would be a roadblock for someone who is copying code that they don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains()` method for this purpose like

```
relatedlist.Where(i => !relatedItemsList.Contains(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Union and SelectMany linq methods:

```
relatedList = relatedList.Union(baseList.SelectMany(baseItem => GetRelatedItems(baseItem)));
```

Edit: Sorry I read your question too quickly and assumed relatedList was as list of strings. To use the Union method for object you would have to write an IEqualityComparer for your class.

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        return x.id == y.id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass item)
    {
        return item.id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

relatedList = relatedList.Union(baseList.SelectMany(baseItem => GetRelatedItems(baseItem)), new MyComparer());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `relatedList.Distinct().toList()` after calling addRange. Distinct removes duplicate elements. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will remove duplicates, but I don't think it solves the problem of not adding items that are in `baseList`, which is the problem that OP is trying to solve.